# Removing plot titles from a series of R plots

Tags: r, visualization

I have a long R script that does data analysis and produces a series of plots (approximately 20) having Titles using the native `plot(main="foo")` syntax.

Sometimes (e.g. for embedding in a Word Report where there will be Figure Captions) I need the exact same plots but without the titles produced by  `plot(main="foo")` syntax.

Any way to do this in an elegant way without maintaining two versions of the file or manually editing out the `main=foo` parameter or having a lot of ugly `if then` blocks with two versions of the same code.

I was hoping I could set a boolean at the start of the code `with_titles =T` or `with_titles=F` and do some sort of magic with `par()` or similar.

Any ideas?

Comment: `par('col.main')`

Comment: How about two vectors at the beginning of the code both called `titles`.  One with the 20 figure titles so that each plot has `main="titles[1]`, etc. The second has the same name but has 20 empty ("") values. Toggle between the two with an if / else at the top or just use # to comment out the line you do not need.